# GNU screen version confusion

Tags: linux, debian, gnu-screen, debian-jessie

I try to use **mousetrack on** in screen in Debian Jessie, and it is supported from version 4.1 [Mouse in screen(1) on the Linux console?](https://superuser.com/questions/127162/mouse-in-screen1-on-the-linux-console)

But there are some confusion in the screen version.

```
dpkg -s screen: "Version: 4.2.1-3"
screen -v: "Screen version 4.02.01 (GNU) 28-Apr-14“
```

How to run screen 4.2 instead of 4.02?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the GNU screen project itself inserts leadings zeros into the version numbers reported. Probably to avoid confusion between version numbers like x.11 and x.2 - which one is newer then? x.11 could be the next version after x.10 or just a minor version number bump from x.1 and older than x.2.

Have you actually tried to use this feature?

For me adding `mousetrack on` to my `~/.screenrc` changed behavior for `Ctrl-A : windowlist`. With it I could move the selection of the window with my mouse, without the mouse had no effect. Did no further experiments with it, though.

I did this with Debian Jessie, exactly the same version of screen you have and Konsole as terminal. Might work different for other terminals, though.