# iTerm2 -> ssh -> gnu screen -> split window: scroll wheel not working

Tags: ssh, terminal, gnu-screen, iterm2

I'm using Mac OS X as a workstation. With iTerm2, I connect to a remote host (Ubuntu Server) using this command:

```
ssh -t user@host screen -D -R -R
```

But I can't get the scroll wheel to work correctly, especially when using split windows. When I'm scrolling up I expect to see the scrollback buffer of the current split window; instead, the entire iTerm2 scrollback buffer goes up, revealing part of the output of the commands before the `ssh`.

Putting `termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@` on `~/.screenrc`, as suggested [here](http://slaptijack.com/system-administration/mac-os-x-terminal-and-gnu-screen-scrollback/), both in local and remote home directories, does not change the behavior.

The `TERM` environment variable is `xterm-256color` in both consoles.

Answer (score 3):

The related posting [Mac OS X terminal and GNU screen scrollback](http://slaptijack.com/system-administration/mac-os-x-terminal-and-gnu-screen-scrollback/) essentially advises you to suppress switching to the alternate screen of xterm.  While in the alternate screen, you would not necessarily be able to use the scroll-wheel to see *xterm*'s scrollback.  A program running in `xterm` would only *see* the escape sequences if it enables the xterm mouse protocol.

By default, `screen` does not do this.  It *does* have a setting which enables the mouse protocol, called [`mousetrack`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html):

> This command determines whether ***`screen`*** will watch for mouse clicks.
>   When this command is enabled, regions that have been split in various
>   ways can be selected by pointing to them with a mouse and left-
>   clicking them. Without specifying on or off, the current state is
>   displayed. The default state is determined by the **`"defmousetrack"`**
>   command.

But

- this is a fairly new feature (mentioned in [Mouse in screen(1) on the Linux console?](https://superuser.com/questions/127162/mouse-in-screen1-on-the-linux-console))
- its description does not hint that it will help with scrolling in a window

Instead (see the first couple of links), some users have altered the xterm configuration to send screen-commands as the result of the scrolling wheel.  A drawback to doing that is that it works only for the combination of xterm+screen.

- [How to use mousewheel in GNU Screen](https://www.staldal.nu/tech/2009/01/11/how-to-use-mousewheel-in-gnu-screen/)
- [Using the scrollwheel in GNU screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359109/using-the-scrollwheel-in-gnu-screen)
- [Can mouse wheel scrolling work in a Screen session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18006/can-mouse-wheel-scrolling-work-in-a-screen-session)

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to figure this out too. So far, I have learned that adding this termcapinfo line:

```
termcapinfo xterm 'hs:ts=\E]2;:fs=\007:ds=\E]2;screen\007:ti@:te@'
```

and removing my status line:

```
# change the hardstatus settings to give an window list at the bottom of the
# screen, with the time and date and with the current window highlighted
#hardstatus alwayslastline
#hardstatus string '%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{= kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B} %m-%d %{W}%c %{g}]'
```

will make the mouse scroll work nicely with screen inside of iTerm2.

But, I want my status line :(

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://blog.filippo.io/native-scrolling-and-iterm2/), the following command works for me.

```
$ defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2 AlternateMouseScroll -bool true
```